# How to retreive full Asset Hierarchy in Azure Digital Twins using REST API

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli, azure-sdk-.net, azure-digital-twins

I want to retrieve Asset Hierarchy of Twin Graph in Azure Digital Twins using REST API, is there any way to do so?

Comment: Could add more information to your question? It will help others to answer it. What are you trying to achieve; what have you tried before asking; are you using an existing ontology?

Comment: Hello, I have created a Twin Graph based on an ontology e.g. Organization -> Factories -> Production Line -> Equipments. I want to retrieve this hierarchy through REST API. Currently I am referring to Azure Digital Client SDK but there are no methods available there to retrieve this Asset Hierarchy from Twin Graph

Comment: Have you tried writing a query with multiple joins?

Comment: No, Actually I need full twin graph e.g Select * from DigitalTwins but I want them in Order Hierarchy wise, I am doubtful it is possible using Multiple joins.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you described in your question (and the comments) can be solved by writing multiple queries. To get the full graph as a hierarchy, you will first need to query the top-level items (in your case organisations) and then you can either run a query for every organisation or fit it all into one query. I'm making some assumptions about your hierarchy in these examples, you will need to adapt them to your ontology.

Getting all the organisations:

```sql
SELECT ROOM FROM DIGITALTWINS DT WHERE IS_OF_MODEL(DT, 'dtmi:example:organisation;1', exact)
```

Getting the hierarchy for one organisation:

```sql
SELECT Organisation, Factory, ProductionLine, Equipment
FROM DIGITALTWINS Organisation
JOIN Factory RELATED Organisation.contains
JOIN ProductionLine RELATED Factory.contains
JOIN Equipment RELATED ProductionLine.contains
WHERE Organisation.$dtId = 'Organisation1'
```

Getting the hierarchy for all previously found organisations:

```sql
SELECT Organisation, Factory, ProductionLine, Equipment
FROM DIGITALTWINS Organisation
JOIN Factory RELATED Organisation.contains
JOIN ProductionLine RELATED Factory.contains
JOIN Equipment RELATED ProductionLine.contains
WHERE Organisation.$dtId IN ['Organisation1', 'Organisation2', 'Organisation3', 'etc...']
```

There is a limitation of 5 JOIN statements to take into account. And both queries will return a row for every Equipment twin, so you will need to transform the result a bit.

In both the SDK and REST API, you can achieve this through the [Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/digital-twins/dataplane/query/querytwins?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) operation.